# How do you change boolean value of post in show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, boolean, hidden-field

Im trying to set up a button that will flag a post as inappropriate.

Ive set up a hidden form for the button that will set the `:flag` boolean value to `true` but this is down in the show.html.erb file. When I submit the button I get a blank page that says `not allowed`. Any help would be appreciated!

---

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_account!, except: [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  
def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
   params.fetch(:post, {}).permit(:title,:contact , :content, :category_id, :genre_id, :city_id, :instrument_id, :flag)
end
```

Hidden form in show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post, {:url => post_path(@post), :method=>:patch} do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :flag, value: true %>
  <%= f.submit 'flag', class: 'btn btn-warning' %>
<% end %>
```

migration AddFlagToPost

```
class AddFlagToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :posts, :flag, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the way you set the hidden field value, you should use `value: true` instead of the `value: = true`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :flag, value: true %>
```

Comment: I just changed it to your suggestion. Sadly it did not fix the issue. code looks nicer though! thank you! i will edit it my post.

Comment: Oh I see, a method not allowed code could be returned for multiple reasons, I would suggest you to check that you have defined the route for the update action of your controller, in that case, you can add the 'method: :patch' option in the form_for helper to update the value.

Comment: Thank you Ivan! ive tried to find ways to adjust the code for a patch method and I seem to get the same message. The code I tried this and got the same result:


<%= form_for @post, {:url => post_path(@post), :method=>:patch} do |f| %>

Comment: Instead of setting a `hidden_field` in the form, why don't you consider adding in a `member` route? in my opinion that would be the best approach.

Comment: I am a bit of a novice at rails. How would I implement a member route?

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb`

```rb
resources :posts do
  patch "inappropriate", on: :member
end
```

Next, you need to define the action in your `controller`

```rb
def inappropriate
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.update(flag: true)
end
```

Then in your `view` file

```rb
<%= form_with url: post_inappropriate_url(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Flag" %>
<% end %>
```

Please check the url using `rails routes` and then modify the `form url` accordingly.

Comment: rails routs showed it as :
`inappropriate_post PATCH  /posts/:id/inappropriate(.:format)                                                       posts#inappropriate`

and the form was changed to:
`<%= form_with url: inappropriate_post_path(@post) do |f| %>`

this time, the flag button did not break the site but the console read as such: 
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/posts/1/inappropriate")`